# Quickblox messages not saved + group dialog creation timeout

Tags: quickblox

Since a few hours my chat messages are not saved anymore on Quickblox.
I can send the messages (text/content) without any problem but I don’t see the messages appearing anymore in the admin panel.

When I want to fetch the messages for a dialog, I only get old messages.

Also doesn't succeed in creating a group chat dialog. Tried it on admin  panel + iOS and Android application.

status.quickblox.com is also offline, is there a server issue?

Anyone else experiencing issues?

Thank you,

Wouter Goossens

Comment: What plan are you on? http://quickblox.com/plans/

Answer (score 0):

There were Chat server overload issues, now everything is green again

Do you still have any issues with your mobile apps?